# How to check each line of a text file for a string and print all lines with occurrences of that word to a new text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to write a script that reads a text file line by line, and transfers all lines with an occurrences of a specific `str`, for example (if the line has the string `'apple'` or `'Hello World'`), to a new text file.

```
fpath = open('Redshift_twb.txt', 'r')
lines = fpath.readlines()

fpath_write = open('Redshift_new.txt', 'w+')

print(lines[0:10])


fpath_write.write(lines[0:10])

fpath.close()
fpath_write.close()
```

Currently, I just have the basics set up, but I am stuck because when I use `.readlines()` it adds all the lines to a list at separate indexes. Then when I try to write back to a new file, I get an error message:

```
fpath_write.write(lines[0:10])
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

Because you cannot use the function `.write()` on a `list`.

I know this is a two part question, but any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Read the lines in the input file
- *Filter* the list to find the lines that you need to write to the output file
- `join` whose lines with `\n` - to stitch together a single string
- Write that string to the output file

```
fpath = open('Redshift_twb.txt', 'r')
lines = fpath.readlines()

fpath_write = open('Redshift_new.txt', 'w+')

print(lines[0:10])

# filter the list; with the string 'apple'
# replace 'apple' with whatever string you want to find
out_lines = [line for line in lines if 'apple' in line]

# Join the lines into a single string
output = '\n'.join(out_lines)

# write it
fpath_write.write(output)

fpath.close()
fpath_write.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `fpath_write.write(lines[0:10])` with this `fpath_write.write(''.join(line for line in lines[0:10] if 'content1' in line))`